# Combining two mysql queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two sql queries...

```
set  @count:=0;
select @count:=@count+1 as SNO, col1, col2 FROM table;
```

I want to combine above queries into a single query. Any Help?

Comment: example for expected output ?

Comment: if you're initializing @count to 0 and then simply incrementing it by 1, why not just set it to 1 in the first place?

Comment: He is looking for Row_Number function in MySQL.. I believe

Comment: i want to do increment for each row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do this,

```
select @count:=@count+1 as SNO, col1, col2 
FROM table, (SELECT @count:=0) r ;
```

Just like adding RowNumber for each row

```
select @rownum:=@rownum+1 ‘rank’, 
       p.* 
from player p, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r 
order by score 
desc limit 10;
```

**[Adding RowNumber in MySQL](http://jimlife.wordpress.com/2008/09/09/displaying-row-number-rownum-in-mysql/)**

Answer (score 2):

As per my understanding,you are looking for Row_Number function in this case. If this is correct, please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql)

e.g.

```
Select @count := @count + 1 As SNO, col1, col2
From table ,(SELECT @count:=0) foo
```

may help

Also you can refer [ROW_NUMBER, Partition, and Over in MySQL](http://briansteffens.com/2011/07/19/row_number-partition-and-over-in-mysql/) for more understanding on the same

Answer (score 1):

Combining two queries..

```
SELECT t1.field1, t1.field2, t2.field1
FROM (query1) as t1, (query2) as t2
WHERE t1.field1= t2.field1
```

Hope this will works ...

Answer (score 0):

```
select @count:=@count+1 as SNO, col1, col2 FROM table, (SELECT @count:=0) t;
```